# Nested element (web component) can't get its template

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, html-imports, html5-template

I made a simple example using Web Components with two custom elements (v1) where one is nested in another.
index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="import" href="app-container.html">
</head>
<body>
  <app-container></app-container>
</body>
</html>
```

app-container.html:

```html
<link rel="import" href="toolbar.html">
<template id="app-container">
  <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
</template>
<script>
  customElements.define('app-container', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
      const content = document.currentScript.ownerDocument.querySelector('#app-container').content;
      shadowRoot.appendChild(content.cloneNode(true));
    }
  });
</script>
```

toolbar.html:

```html
<template id="app-toolbar">
  <p>Ok!</p>
</template>
<script>
  customElements.define('app-toolbar', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
      const content = document.currentScript.ownerDocument.querySelector('#app-toolbar').content;
      shadowRoot.appendChild(content.cloneNode(true));
    }
  });
</script>
```

But in the toolbar.html `document.currentScript` is the same as in the app-container.html and hence `querySelector('#app-toolbar')` can't find template with id `app-toolbar`. How to solve this problem?

Example tested on Chrome 55 (without polyfill).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`document.currentScript` contains a reference to the script that is currently parsed and executed. Therefore it is not valid anymore for your purpose when the  `constructor()` function is called (from another script).

Instead you shoud save its value in a variable at the beginning of the script, and use this variable in the constructor:

```
<script>
    var currentScript = document.currentScript
    customElements.define( ... )
    ...
</script>
```

If you have multiple scripts, you should use distinct names.

Alternately, you can encapsulate the ephemeral value in a closure:

```
(function(owner) {
    customElements.define('app-container', class extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
           super();
           let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
           const content = owner.querySelector('#app-container').content;
           shadowRoot.appendChild(content.cloneNode(true));
        }
    });
})(document.currentScript.ownerDocument);
```

Here the value `document.currentScript.ownerDocument` is assigned to the `owner` argument which is still defined correctly when `constructor()` is called.

`owner` is locally defined so you can use the same name in the other document.

Comment: @Supersharp you are my hero!