# Reference to template tag in web component

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, html5-template

This my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="import" href="component.html">

</head>

<body>
    <tag-name></tag-name>
</body>

</html>
```

and this is my component.html

```
<template>
    <style></style>
    <div>test</div>
</template>
<script>
    customElements.define('tag-name', class extends HTMLElement {

        constructor() {
            super();
            /*var tmpl = document.querySelector('link[href$="component.html"]').import
                .querySelector('template').content.cloneNode(true);*/


            var currentScript = document.currentScript;
            var tmpl = currentScript.previousSibling.content.cloneNode(true);
            this.attachShadow({
                mode: 'open'
            }).appendChild(tmpl);
        }

    });

</script>
```

I tried to don't use ' ...querySelector('link[href$="component.html"]').import ..' I've inserted it in comment. I wanted to reference to template tag without insert 'component.html'. It doesn't work but I don't understand why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [web component (vanilla, no polymer): how to load <template> content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091849/web-component-vanilla-no-polymer-how-to-load-template-content)

Comment: I don't know it, thank you.