# Not able to render vanilla webcomponent imported as template

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I am trying to build a webcomponent and import it in main HTML file.

my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="import" href="./tile.html">
</head>
<body>
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick="buildTile()">Build</a>

  <ns-tile /> <!-- Works -->

  <div id="ns-search-results"></div>
<script> 
  async function buildTile() { 
    const results = document.getElementById('ns-search-results'); 
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
      var nsTile = document.createElement('ns-tile'); 
      results.appendChild(nsTile); 
    } 
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`tile.html`

```
<template id="ns-item-tile"> 
  <style> </style> 
  <div class="tile"> Tile content </div>
</template>
<script> 
class NSTile extends HTMLElement { 
  constructor() {
    super();
  } 

  connectedCallback() { 
    var importedDoc = document.currentScript.ownerDocument; 
    let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }); 
    const t = importedDoc.querySelector('#ns-item-tile'); 
    const instance = t.content.cloneNode(true); 
    shadowRoot.appendChild(instance); 

    function init() { 
      const head = shadowRoot.querySelector('.tile'); 
      head.addEventListener("click", function () { 
        console.log('click'); 
      }); 
    } 
    init(); 
  } 
} // init the element

customElements.define("ns-tile", NSTile);
</script>
```

When I use `<ns-tile />` directly in index.html, content renders properly. But when I try to render it inside a `for` loop in `buildTile` method, I am getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null
    at HTMLElement.connectedCallback (tile.html:16)`

How can I access the html template inside `tile.html` so I can build using `for` loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [web component (vanilla, no polymer): how to load <template> content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091849/web-component-vanilla-no-polymer-how-to-load-template-content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

1. Custom elements are never self closing. `<ns-tile />` should be replaced with `<ns-tile></ns-tile>`
2. `<link rel="import" href="">` is dead. Just load the script file normally or use [ES6 Import](https://devdocs.io/javascript/statements/import) instead.
3. If you do continue to use `link rel="import"` then you must move `var importedDoc = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;` outside of your class.
4. I don't see anywhere that you are "defining" your component: `customElements.define('tag-name', className);`

Here are some changes to the component file. If you change it to a JS file then it can look like this:

```js
const template = `<style></style> 
<div class="tile"> Tile content </div>
`;

class NSTile extends HTMLElement { 
  constructor() {
    super();
    let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }); 
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = template; 

    const head = shadowRoot.querySelector('.tile'); 
    head.addEventListener("click", function () { 
      console.log('click'); 
    }); 
  } 
}

customElements.define('ns-tile', NSTile);
```

```html
<ns-tile></ns-tile>
```

Comment: "I don't see anywhere that you are "defining" your component" it was, but because of wrong formatting it was outside code block; just fixed that

Comment: Thanks @skyboyer @intevalia thanks for your code. This will work. So I assume we cannot use `template` per se for this then. I will refactor the code as you suggested.

Comment: You can use `<template>` in HTML files. But not the same way in JS files. You can create a template in code `document.createElement('template')` but ES6 template literals are easier and smaller.