# Universal WebComponents import

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I'm currently working on `WebComponent` using `plain HTML` and `VanillaJS`. The objective is to provide a working collection of `Components` for the company to use.

```
<template id="x-intranet-alert">
    <div class="alert">
        <p></p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    class IntranetAlert extends HTMLElement {
        static get observedAttributes() {
            return ['message', 'type', 'close']
        }

        constructor() {
            super()

            this.innerHTML = document.currentScript.ownerDocument.querySelector('#x-intranet-alert').innerHTML
        }

        attributeChangedCallback(attr, oldValue, newValue) {
            switch(attr) {
                case 'type':
                    this.querySelector("div").className = `alert ${newValue}`
                    break

                // ...
            }
        }
    }

    customElements.define('intranet-alert', IntranetAlert);
</script>
```

This is working fine if I'm doing it in `HTML`

```
<intranet-alert type="info" message="Je suis une alert de type info" close="true"></intranet-alert>
```

But if I try to create it programmatically I have an error because `document.currentScript.ownerDocument` is `document` and not the components document.

```
let alert = new IntranetAlert()
alert.setAttribute("type", "danger")
alert.setAttribute("message", "Component créé dynamiquement")

document.querySelector("#alert").appendChild(alert)
```

How can I import the document so it works on both way?

Comment: Look at this anwser: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41409299/4600982

Comment: I feel dumb, I did not find this question during my research. Many thanks!